# Couchbase can not access web console

Tags: vagrant, couchbase, centos6

I am running a Vagrant machine on Windows 10 using CentOS 6.7 and have installed Couchbase.
For some reason I can not access the couchbase admin from the browser.
When testing with `telnet 192.168.56.101 8091` I get this:

```
Connected to 192.168.56.101.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Active network connections:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11209               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11210               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52491               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21100               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59276               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21101               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9998              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8091                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8092                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::11209                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::34761                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::11210                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::11211                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:925                 0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:948               0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211               0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36985               0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 192.168.56.101:123          0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:123               0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 :::925                      :::*
udp        0      0 :::11211                    :::*
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*
udp        0      0 :::59379                    :::*
udp        0      0 fe80::a00:27ff:fee4:ce95:123 :::*
udp        0      0 ::1:123                     :::*
udp        0      0 fe80::a00:27ff:fe25:a210:123 :::*
udp        0      0 :::123                      :::*
```

I have also tried disabling the windows firewall but the problem persists.